# How to make a <input type="text"/> scale with height as it receives more text

Tags: php, html, input, laravel

The text on the input goes to the right when the input receives too much text, how do you make it so that the input scales downwards to make all the text be seen

Comment: Turn it into a textarea?

Comment: why did you tag `php`?

Comment: even if it's textarea, the text does not scale downwards, it will still look the same if the input gets too many text

Comment: I'm using php, to create these

Comment: You don't tag your questions with Windows because you're using windows :P Laravel and PHP are completely non-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input type text is always single line. you can use  for multi-line and you can specify rows and columns. Look at this: http://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/ for auto resizing textareas and other tricks.

Answer (score 6):

The right element to use for this is a `<textarea>`. `<input type="text">` doesn't allow line breaks in its content, so it can never wrap to a second line.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean you want to adjust height of text area, write specific height and width with

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Then you'll get scroll bar on the right side.

Comment: They wanted it small at first, then the height should resize as it receives text, so static assignment is a no go, thanks anyway :)

Comment: i think it can be solved by javascript,, pure html is definitely wont satisfy your requirement

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Autosize is a plugin to enable automatic height for textarea elements. It does exactly what you need.

It is really easy to use

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/